# Adding PCL (Point Cloud Library) to existing project with Makefiles

Tags: makefile, cmake, point-cloud-library

I have a problem with PCL: specifically I want to use it in the existing project with existing Makefiles. However, PCL is using CMake and I couldn't find how to add it to Makefile directly. Does anyone know how to do that?

Comment: What's the question here? How to link to the library? How to get the library built by your makefile automatically? Something else?

Comment: Yes, how to link the PCL directly in the Makefile.

Comment: How to link to a given library has nothing to do with how that library is built. Are you just asking how to add the correct flags to your link command so that your binary is linked to the system available PCL library?

Comment: Sorry, I'm a beginner in the topic, so I don't fully understand what you are saying. What I'm asking will be better rephrased to "how to translate the cmake code from here http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/using_pcl_pcl_config.php#using-pcl-pcl-config directly to a code in a makefile". So that I can use PCL in my project.

Comment: `make` doesn't have an equivalent to that construction. That's what the autotools are for. Whether you need something like that at all depends on how PCL gets installed (though assuming that's there you probably do need it). Does PCL install a `pkg-config` `.pc` file?

Comment: I couldn't find anything by typing in shell [pkg-config --libs pcl] and [pkg-config --cflags pcl], if that's a correct way to check of course.

Comment: Try `pkg-config --list-all | less` and look for PCL/pcl/etc.? It may also not be in a standard location. But I think that's mainly what cmake uses to find libraries so hopefully it works correctly.

Comment: I see different pcl libraries! Specifically pcl_registration-1.7, pcl_io-1.7 and pcl_common-1.7 are the ones I need. How can I now add them to makefile?

Comment: You need to add the output of `pkg-config --libs pcl_registration-1.7`, `pkg-config --cflags pcl_registration-1.7`, etc. to your makefile's compilation and linker flags. How you do that in your makefile depends on your makefile's contents.

Comment: That's almost there! Now I get "/usr/include/boost/system/error_code.hpp:222: undefined reference to `boost::system::generic_category()'". And this error doesn't appear if I compile makefile without these additions. I guess what you've said substitutes "include_directories(${PCL_INCLUDE_DIRS})
link_directories(${PCL_LIBRARY_DIRS})" in CMake, and what about "add_definitions(${PCL_DEFINITIONS})"?

Comment: Ok, I added -lboost_system and now it compiles fine. Etan, thanks a ton for help! Will read more about this.

Answer (score 2):

First try to compile the one of the example provided in PCL website using CMake.
http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/pcl_visualizer.php

After compiling the above example, you will find various new files and a folder created by CMake in your directory.

Go to CMakeFiles/pcl_visualizer_demo.dir/ .
Open file named link.txt, which contains the terminal command which has various pcl(point cloud libraries) linked dynamically to the file.

command should look similar to the command shown below

`/usr/bin/c++   -O3  -Wno-deprecated  -s  CMakeFiles/pcl_visualizer_demo.dir  -o pcl_visualizer_demo -rdynamic -lpcl_common -Wl,-Bstatic -lflann_cpp_s -Wl,-Bdynamic -lpcl_kdtree -lpcl_octree -lpcl_search -lqhull -lpcl_surface -lpcl_sample_consensus -lpcl_io -lpcl_filters -lpcl_features -lpcl_keypoints -lpcl_registration -lpcl_segmentation -lpcl_recognition -lpcl_visualization -lpcl_people -lpcl_outofcore -lpcl_tracking /usr/lib/libvtkGenericFiltering.so.5.8.0 /usr/lib/libvtkGeovis.so.5.8.0 /usr/lib/libvtkCharts.so.5.8.0 /usr/lib/libvtkViews.so.5.8.0 /usr/lib/libvtkInfovis.so.5.8.0 /usr/lib/libvtkWidgets.so.5.8.0`

You can include these libraries in your Makefile directly.

If you use different functions or pcl headers files, then first try compiling it using CMake and get the libraries linked and add it to your Makefile of previous project.

I tried this method for my project which worked perfectly fine. I tried `pkg-config` to link the libraries, which didn't work in my case. I was not able to find any other method that easily links all the required libraries.